# UBUNTU 16.04 - wifi stopped working after fixed "/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"

Tags: wireless, sudo

I missed up my chmod -R 777, but have now fixed it on secure boot.
But after that my wifi stopped working. Have already restarted both network service and manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a video on how to fix wifi not working in ubuntu by reinstalling the driver: https://youtu.be/J4O_LwiXwNk if that doesn't fix it, maybe try sudo rfkill unblock all. My wifi got disabled after secure boot too, but I managed to fix it. Also check that you have not enabled flight mode by accident, and also note that for me at least the flight mode light on my keyboard is on when flight mode is off for linux, while it is normal in windows, so try pressing the flight mode button on your keyboard if you have one :)